# How to improve SQL query performance with a lot of inner selects?

Tags: sql, performance, select, subquery, case

How can I change this SQL query to improve performance?

I need to select name, address, phone, etc from Client, Supplier or Contact depending on `EntityID` (`EntidadeID`)

- `EntidadeID = 1` gets data from `Clients` table
- `EntidadeID = 2` gets data from `Supplier` table
- `EntidadeID = 3` gets data from `Contacts` table

SQL code:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View_AtivTecnicasAtivTecnicasMatSer]
AS
    SELECT        
        a.Numero, a.UserFullName, a.Data, a.Hora, a.CodigoTerceiro, 
        a.Contacto, a.Tarefa, a.UserTarefaNome, a.AFaturar, a.Resolvido, 
        a.AgendadaData, a.AgendadaHora, a.AlertaData, a.AlertaHora, 
        a.Execucao, a.NotasInternas, a.ResolvidoData, a.ResolvidoHora, 
        a.ResolvidoUserFullName, a.NumeroAtendInicial, a.EmailCliente, 
        a.EmailUserTarefa, a.PDFTarefaAnexo, a.DataNotifInformativa, 
        a.DataNotifResolucao, a.TipoDoc, a.UserTarefaAlertado, 
        a.Origem, a.Anulado, a.TotalSIVA, a.TotalCIVA, a.Moeda, a.Cambio, 
        a.TaxaDesconto, a.TipoPreco, dbo.WR_Temas.Descricao, 
        CASE 
           WHEN EntidadeID = 1 THEN
                             (SELECT        Descricao
                               FROM            dbo.WR_ClientesEstab
                               WHERE        ID = a.ClienteEstabID) 
        END AS Estab, 
        CASE 
           WHEN a.EntidadeID = 1 THEN
                             (SELECT        Morada
                               FROM            dbo.WR_ClientesEstab
                               WHERE        ID = a.ClienteEstabID) 
           WHEN a.EntidadeID = 2 THEN
                             (SELECT        Morada
                               FROM            dbo.WR_Fornecedores
                               WHERE        Codigo = a.CodigoTerceiro) 
        END AS Morada, 
        CASE 
           WHEN a.EntidadeID = 1 THEN
                             (SELECT        Localidade
                               FROM            dbo.WR_ClientesEstab
                               WHERE        ID = a.ClienteEstabID) 
           WHEN a.EntidadeID = 2 THEN
                             (SELECT        Localidade
                               FROM            dbo.WR_Fornecedores
                               WHERE        Codigo = a.CodigoTerceiro) 
        END AS Localidade, 
        CASE 
           WHEN a.EntidadeID = 1 THEN
                             (SELECT        CodPostal
                               FROM            dbo.WR_ClientesEstab
                               WHERE        ID = a.ClienteEstabID) 
           WHEN a.EntidadeID = 2 THEN
                             (SELECT        CodPostal
                               FROM            dbo.WR_Fornecedores
                               WHERE        Codigo = a.CodigoTerceiro) 
        END AS CodPostal, CASE WHEN a.EntidadeID = 1 THEN
                             (SELECT        Telefone
                               FROM            dbo.WR_ClientesEstab
                               WHERE        ID = a.ClienteEstabID) END AS TelefoneEstab, CASE WHEN a.EntidadeID = 1 THEN
                             (SELECT        Telemovel
                               FROM            dbo.WR_ClientesEstab
                               WHERE        ID = a.ClienteEstabID) END AS TelemovelEstab, CASE WHEN a.EntidadeID = 1 THEN
                             (SELECT        Nome
                               FROM            dbo.WR_Clientes
                               WHERE        Codigo = a.CodigoTerceiro) WHEN a.EntidadeID = 2 THEN
                             (SELECT        Empresa
                               FROM            dbo.WR_Contactos
                               WHERE        ID = a.TerceiroID) WHEN a.EntidadeID = 3 THEN
                             (SELECT        Nome
                               FROM            dbo.WR_Fornecedores
                               WHERE        Codigo = a.CodigoTerceiro) END AS NomeTerceiro, CASE WHEN a.EntidadeID = 1 THEN
                             (SELECT        Telefone
                               FROM            dbo.WR_Clientes
                               WHERE        Codigo = a.CodigoTerceiro) WHEN a.EntidadeID = 2 THEN
                             (SELECT        Telefone
                               FROM            dbo.WR_Contactos
                               WHERE        ID = a.TerceiroID) WHEN a.EntidadeID = 3 THEN
                             (SELECT        Telefone
                               FROM            dbo.WR_Fornecedores
                               WHERE        Codigo = a.CodigoTerceiro) END AS Telefone, CASE WHEN a.EntidadeID = 1 THEN
                             (SELECT        Telemovel
                               FROM            dbo.WR_Clientes
                               WHERE        Codigo = a.CodigoTerceiro) WHEN a.EntidadeID = 2 THEN
                             (SELECT        Telemovel
                               FROM            dbo.WR_Contactos
                               WHERE        ID = a.TerceiroID) WHEN a.EntidadeID = 3 THEN
                             (SELECT        Telemovel
                               FROM            dbo.WR_Fornecedores
                               WHERE        Codigo = a.CodigoTerceiro) END AS Telemovel, CASE WHEN a.EntidadeID = 1 THEN
                             (SELECT        Contribuinte
                               FROM            dbo.WR_Clientes
                               WHERE        Codigo = a.CodigoTerceiro) WHEN a.EntidadeID = 2 THEN
                             (SELECT        Contribuinte
                               FROM            dbo.WR_Contactos
                               WHERE        ID = a.TerceiroID) WHEN a.EntidadeID = 3 THEN
                             (SELECT        Contribuinte
                               FROM            dbo.WR_Fornecedores
                               WHERE        Codigo = a.CodigoTerceiro) END AS Contribuinte, m.Linha, m.ArtigoCod, m.ArtigoDesc, m.Qtd, m.UN, m.ValorUnitario, m.DescontoPercentual, m.DescontoValor, m.Armazem, m.NumSerie, m.AnoERP, m.SerieERP, 
                         m.TipoDocERP, m.NumDocERP, m.DataExportadoERP, m.UserExportouERP, m.TaxaIva, m.TotalDescontos AS TotalDescontosLinha, m.TotalGeral AS TotalGeralLinhas, m.Ordenacao, m.ExportadaERP, m.DocERP, 
                         m.DescontoPercentual2, m.DescontoPercentual3, a.TotalMercadoria, a.TotalLiquido, a.TotalIVA, a.TotalGeral, a.TotalGeralEuros, a.TotalDescontosLinhas, a.TotalDescontosGlobal, a.TotalDescontos, a.EntidadeID, 
                         m.DescontoPercentual4
FROM            dbo.WR_AtivTecnicas AS a INNER JOIN
                         dbo.WR_Temas ON a.TemaID = dbo.WR_Temas.ID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.WR_AtivTecnicasMatSer AS m ON a.Numero = m.NumeroAtiv
GO
```

I tried to make only 3 Select Cases with all the fields, but without success.

Comment: Do a LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: It is impossible to help without your database model (tables, keys, indexes, etc..).
Some investigation tips: rethink your db model, use joint tables, use indexes, split complexity with a script doing separate queries instead of a huge one.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this:
as @jarlh mentioned, you can replace your selects in cases with left join,also since you have these rules in place :

```
EntidadeID = 1 gets data from Clients table
EntidadeID = 2 gets data from Supplier table
EntidadeID = 3 gets data from Contacts table
```

you can include them in your join criteria , so you can remove cases completely as  example below:

```
SELECT
    *
     -- instead of case for example for Telemovel
    , COALESCE( ct.Telemovel, st.Telemovel, cts.Telemovel)
    -- replace all the case statements following above logic
FROM
    dbo.WR_AtivTecnicas                  AS A
    INNER JOIN dbo.WR_Temas
        ON A.TemaID = dbo.WR_Temas.ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.WR_AtivTecnicasMatSer AS m
        ON A.Numero = m.NumeroAtiv
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ClientsTable ct
      ON  ct.Codigo = a.CodigoTerceiro -- replace with proper condition
      AND EntidadeID = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SupplierTable st
      ON  st.id = A.id  -- replace with proper condition
      AND EntidadeID = 2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ContactsTable cts
      ON  cts.ID = a.TerceiroID  -- replace with proper condition 
      AND EntidadeID = 3
```